# Bad Assignment, Logical Operators

Tags: javascript

Am learning Javascript in code academy. This is the test I have been  given,

"Inside the eat function, create an if statement that returns true only if both hungry and foodHere are true, and false otherwise."

My code below is executing but it has a warning. What could be the problem?

```
var hungry = true;
var foodHere = true;

var eat = function() {

  if(hungry && foodHere){
      console.log("I am hungry");
  }else if(hungry && foodHere = false){
      console.log("Choose one");
  }


};
eat();
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator. `==` is a comparison operator. Even better, use `!foodHere` instead of `foodHere == false`. Up to you to figure out what `!` means.

Comment: they say nothing about a console.log ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var hungry = true;
var foodHere = true;

var eat = function() {

  if(hungry && foodHere){
      console.log("I am hungry");
  }else {
      console.log("Choose one");
  }


};
eat();
```

the problem was, that you tried to assign a value in the condition `foodHere = false`. If you want to compare things you need `==` and if you want to be sure that the types are the same use `===`.
But you don't need that condition at all!

The assignment want you to return a boolean value (`true` or `false`) and not to print something, so i guess your code should look like this:

```
var hungry = true;
var foodHere = true;

var eat = function() {
  return (hungry && foodHere)
};

eat();
```

Answer (score 2):

Single = is for assignment, == is for comparison

```
var hungry = true;
var foodHere = true;

var eat = function() {

  if(hungry && foodHere){
      console.log("I am hungry");
  }else if(hungry && foodHere == false){
      console.log("Choose one");
  }


};
eat();
```

Anyways, you don't need the second comparison since if the first one is false it will always go through the else

Answer (score 1):

I just want to give additional information for emilioicai's answer, there are two kind of "equal comparison" in JavaScript

1. equal to ( == )
2. exactly equal to ( === )

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 0):

= is for assignment, == is for value comparison and === is for value and datatype comparison. So you can use == while comparing with the false. But this is not the best practice. We always uses '!' negation operator while converting true to false

```
var hungry = true;
var foodHere = true;

var eat = function() {

  if(hungry && foodHere){
      console.log("I am hungry");
  }else if(!hungry || !foodHere){
      console.log("Choose one");
  }
};
eat()
```

I am using || operator assuming that any one needs to be false.You can go for && if both false are required